# Building opencv from source in Mac m1

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, cmake, apple-m1

I'm using the following Make to build OpenCV from source,

```
 cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
  -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/Tools/opencv_contrib/modules \
  -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/miniforge/base/envs/envname/bin/python3 \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D WITH_TBB=ON \
    -D WITH_V4L=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
     -DBUILD_ZLIB=OFF \
  -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/Tools/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Unfortunately it doesn't build. It throws the following error,

```
: error: unknown type name 'AVBSFContext'; did you mean 'AVIOContext'?
```

I have of course installed FFmpeg. what am I still missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you've installed ffmpeg 5 and OpenCV is not yet compatible with it. Please try the following:

```
brew install ffmpeg@4
brew unlink ffmpeg
brew link ffmpeg@4
```

and then recompile OpenCV again.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately, it is still throwing the same error :(

Comment: If all went fine then you should see something like:

/opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers

Comment: Also after linking to ffmpeg4 please do the build from scratch. The easiest way is to remove the content of build directory first. It is the dir you are in executing the cmake

Comment: it works. thank you! I had to completely uninstall `ffmpeg@5`. mere unlink-link didn't work for me. I have got one last question. Sometimes it throws 'zlib has no make target specified` hence i have disabled zlib. Is there any ways to install zlib in mac m1? I tried using brew but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Would executing `xcode-select --install` prior to running cmake help?